# PHP mysqldump doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, system

I've the code shown below but nothing happens after execution

`system('mysqldump -u USER -pPASS DB > /tmp/bckp.sql');`

What is wrong with this code?

Sultan

Comment: if you run that command from the command line, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there could be thausands of things going wrong:

- do you get any error messages?
- have you tried to `echo system(...` - and whats the result?
- what is the [return value](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.system.php)?
- have you tried to use exec or passthru instead?
- are you sure your db-name, user and password are spelled correctly?
- what happens if you fire that command on the terminal on your own?

some more information would be realy useful to help you.

Comment: If execute this command directly from my console it works well, but via php script it doesn't

Comment: Seems there were restrictions on executing of a system commands, so for now it works

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to specify the full path to mysqldump as it probably isn't in your PATH environment variable for the user PHP is running as. Go to command line on the server and run

```
which mysqldump
```

It will spit out the full path. Then replace *mysqldump* in your `system()` command with that full path

Comment: which is a command not recognized on windows systems. There another one to know the absolute path?